# DynamoDb: Thousands of item to write with low capacity

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I just started writing some Lambda functions, my problem is this one:
I have around 7000 items to write.
Those items are having two index the primary the id and a secondary the spotname.
To write all those functions in the dynamodb with a batch write i wrote this code:
Unfortunately i face an issue with the batchwrite (25 items limit) and i solved it in the following way:

```
for (var j = 0; j < event.length; j++){
        if(event[j][0] && event[j][1] && event[j][2] && event[j][3]){
            requests.push(new Station(event[j][0],event[j][1],event[j][2],event[j][3]));
            if(requests.length == 25 || j == (event.length -1)) { // when you have 25 ready..
                var params = {
                    RequestItems: {
                         'Stations': requests
                        }
                };
                requests=[];
                DynamoDB.batchWrite(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log("Error while batchWrite into dynamoDb");
                        console.log(err);
                    } 
                    else{
                         console.log("Pushed all the added elements");
                    }
                });   
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, i noticed that with a low capacity:
Table   Read: 5  Write: 5
spotname-index  Read:  5 Write: 5

I manage to write in the database only 1500 records.
Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, this is how I solved it.

Increase the capacity for short period of time. Learnt it is by the hour. If you increase the capacity, try to use it within one hour. Then bring it down.

You cannot bring it down more than 4 times as of now. So you get 4 times in a day to bring your capacity down. You can increase the write capacity any number of times.

Second Approach is,

You can control the rate of write to Dynamo, so you spread your writes evenly across your capacity.

Make sure you write capacity is always higher than the incoming average record capacity.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using the batch write API for DynamoDB doesn't actually use less throughput.  It is really intended to reduce the amount of overhead for the HTTP requests when sending a large number of requests to DynamoDB.  However, this means that one or more of the items that was attempted to be written may fail and it is your responsibility to detect this and retry those requests.  This is likely why some of the records are not ending up in the database.  To fix this issue you should look at the response to the batch write and retry those writes yourself.

In contrast, when putting single records at a time the AWS SDK will automatically retry.  If you a are using a single thread as in the case above and switch to not using batch while your requests will definitely be throttled they will be given time to retry and succeed which just slows down the execution while keeping the throughput of the table low.

The better option is to temporarily raise the write throughput of the table to a higher value sufficient to support the bulk load.  For this example I'd recommend a value beteen 50 and 100 writes.  A single threaded load operation will likely be rate limited by the round trip time to the DynamoDB API well below these numbers.  For loading only 7000 items I'd recommend avoiding the batch write API as it requires implementing retry logic yourself.  However, if you are loading a lot more data or need the load to complete in less time the batch API can give you a theoretical 25 times performances improvement on the HTTP overhead assuming you are not being throttled.